# How can I run a siddhi app from command prompt?

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I am trying to run a siddhi app from command prompt. What is the command to run the app from command prompt instead of using the editor?

Answer (score 0):

Use the WSO2 SP worker profile, this does not have a GUI and is made lean to run in production. Start the worker though ".bin/worker.sh start" and deploy the Siddhi apps by placing them in /deployment/siddhi-apps.

Refer: https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP430/WSO2+Stream+Processor+Profiles

Comment: I tried the above but its throwing the following error: 

Error on 'testapp'. failed to start the server connectors Error while connecting at Source 'http' at 'MultipleEventsDataStream1'. org.wso2.extension.siddhi.io.http.source.exception.HttpSourceAdaptorRuntimeException: failed to start the server connectors

Comment: Ah seems there is an issue in your siddhi app. Shall we move the discussions to Github with full stack trace? https://github.com/siddhi-io/siddhi/issues

Comment: Sure, please let me know what information you need from me.